# Why is empty insights was receiving from Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have several advertising companies and a test application on Facebook (status: *in development*). When i request meta information on ad objects, I normally receive it. But when I try to get insights on campaigns from API, only an empty array comes back.

```
{ "data": [] }
```

The access token has all the necessary permissions. At the same time, insights from the sandbox comes in well through the same methods (only access token also from the sandbox).

What can be wrong? Does Facebook really allow get insights about real ad campaigns only for published Facebook applications?